# Why do basement blocks above grade show moisture all the time?

Tags: water, basement, foundation, exterior, moisture

At first, I thought maybe it was because the previous owners had laid plastic down in the flower beds so the water was getting trapped underneath the mulch. The soil was basically a mud pit and water will always find a way out. But since I've removed all that, not sure what's still causing this. There is no moisture on interior walls and don’t have a shut off valve (can’t even find pipe!) for outside spigot. Where is this water coming from, and what can I do about it?

[image: photo of flowerbed and foundation]

[image: photo of foundation with PVC vents]

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your basement is considerably more humid than the outdoors.

In general humidity likes to seek out dry air.

The mortar between your cinder blocks is the path of least resistance since cinder blocks have huge voids of air.

Try running a dehumidifier in your basement. I would target within 15% of the outside air. If the relative humidity is 40% outside then aim for 50-60% in your basement.

Comment: I'm not sure how well that will work (though it won't hurt).  If the outside temperature is 30 F with a relative humidity (RH) of 40%, and if the basement temperature is 65 F, the RH in the basement needs to be pushed down to below 10% in order to prevent moisture migration to the outside.  Unless there's something I'm missing.